# How would colonization of different star systems affect safety equipment?

Tags: light, colors

On Earth, most safety equipment as we know it is painted yellow, as well as other high-power machines. Safety jackets worn by construction workers are also as so. Blue light (the majority of the sun's light emissions), is absorbed by these materials best, and so they pop out against the plain urban scenery. However, if around a differently classed star, say Proxima Centauri, where the majority o the light is of another colour, would a different colour be most effective for optimal safety of construction workers and other dangerous jobs?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? The job of the color used is to stand out so picking a color to do that would be the top priority.

Comment: Sun emission spectrum is peaked at yellow, not at blue

Comment: There's a psychological reason and just because it glows strongly in infrared spectrum doesn't mean it is red! The classification is just a convenient way for ID purposes.

Comment: All stars give off almost white light. Their color is only a slight tinge. So perhaps nothing would really be different?

Comment: No, yellow color is not chosen because it's "absorb" blue light the best. It's because it reflect yellow the best. The color with the longest wavelenght (so it won't get bend beetwen reflective material and observer) but it's also the least common color that naturally occur in enviroment.

Comment: Are our friendly interstellar construction workers colonists or locals? Could an answer address how safety equipment colors would vary based on the evolution of eyes around that star - i.e. infrared-seeing aliens - or should it depend on how humans perceive the light reflected by different colors?

Comment: @Zxyrra They are human colonists from earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Colors stay mostly the same**

The easy answer to your question is that colors are more dependent on the eyes of your construction workers than the spectra of the host star. Most humans can only see visible light, and [most stars emit some visible light](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/are-there-stars-that-dont-emit-visible-light).

Therefore, your safety gear should still be colors that reflect the most visible light - namely yellow, white, or reflective/metallic. These colors are most reflective regardless of what wavelength of visible light hits them. The resulting contrast in brightness will create a contrast of colors at visible light levels.

---

### **Dim stars: phosphorescent pigments**

Let's be honest: "the same colors apply" is a boring answer. We can get more specific. Red dwarves emit some visible light, but they are dim to human eyes. Consider using glowing compounds to make safety gear noticeable in a bright environment. Lots of different mineral pigments could provide a variety of colors. You can also just use LEDs and physically light up gear. **Bonus points** if you design uniforms with dark fabric to absorb as much light as possible (retain heat!) contrasted with glowing red/orange pigment. That could be very interesting.

[image: https://geology.com/articles/fluorescent-minerals/]

Comment: Another point in favor of this:  Any atmosphere that humans want to live in will be very similar to our own Nitrogen/Oxygen atmosphere, which tends to absorb and refract wavelengths just outside of the visible spectrum. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(electromagnetic_radiation)